# I need to send data from a feedback form somewhere. Currently using an email, I would like a better way

Tags: java, android

I need to send data from a feedback form somewhere. Currently, the app pulls up a dialog that makes the user select an email client to send it with. The email is pre-populated, so I have properly collected the data from the form. However, I feel as though there is a better way to do this. I haven't worked much with data processing, so I want to know if there is a better way to process and receive the data that the app receives. Sending it in an email seems too clunky. I want the user to be able to input into the form, hit send, and have me recieve whatever they input. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using email is fine for such goal. Alternatively, you can post the information directly to your server using [HTTPClient](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient) if you have Internet access permission.

Comment: If there is a way to send the email without prompting the user (doing it all in the background), then I'd prefer that. But I'm not sure of the best way to do this. How does the HTTPClient work? I read the code for it but I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @coltsfan95 Are you familiar with regular POST action in browser? Like when you submit any form on a website? Basically HTTPClient does the same thing. It can pretend to be a browser and emit GET and POST requests.

Comment: @coltsfan95 Being able to send email on behalf of the user without an explicit process visible to user will be a security concern.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any running web site, maybe you can make http call by another thread in the app and post the data you collected from user.

I am using this method as a solution for something different and it's working fine.